# Accidentally Refunded Offline

Tags: payment-gateway, creditmemo, refund

I accidentally refunded offline. What do I do to make sure the customer is credited on their card?

Answer (score 1):

If you refund offline that means no charge back request was sent to the payment service provider.

If the card was charged in the first place it won't have been cancelled

Comment: Yes, so is there a way to undo an offline credit memo or do an online credit memo and refund the credit card without messing up the magento bookkeeping?

Comment: @Mike honestly, that depends on the way the your bookkeeping is tied to Magento. Best thing to do is do the refund from the payment service provider portal so it's done outside of Magento

Comment: Yeah that's what we currently do.